How to get coordinates from a 3d model in flutter using tap functionality?
I have added a 3-d model in my flutter. let me give you some context about my app. I have a footcare app in which a user can pin-point the place where he/she is feeling pain on tapping on the 3-d model of foot in the app and that point will stored and sent to doctor to diagnose I am using model_viewer_plus  package for showing the model but I don't know how to implement the tapping and getting the point reference functionality in the app. here is the screenshot of my app

so far I have tried this code but this didn't help me.
ModelViewer(
              src: 'assets/models/feet.glb',
              alt: 'A 3D model of an astronaut',
              id: "feet",
              ar: true,
              disableZoom: true,
              cameraControls: true,
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                controller.addJavaScriptChannel(
                  "onModelClick",
                  onMessageReceived: (message) {
                    log("Tapped Position: ${message.message}");
                    setState(() {
                      tappedPosition = message.message;
                    });
                  },
                );

                controller.addJavaScriptChannel(
                  "onClick",
                  onMessageReceived: (message) {
                    log("Tapped Position: ${message.message}");
                    setState(() {
                      tappedPosition = message.message;
                    });
                  },
                );
                controller.runJavaScriptReturningResult('''
                        const modelViewer = document.getElementById('feet');
                        modelViewer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                          const intersection = modelViewer.positionAndNormalFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
                          if (intersection) {
                            onModelClick.postMessage(JSON.stringify(intersection));
                          }
                          Print.postMessage('Hello from Dart');
                        });
                      ''');

                controller.runJavaScript('''
                        const modelViewer = document.querySelector('model-viewer');
                        modelViewer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                          const intersection = modelViewer.positionAndNormalFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
                          if (intersection) {
                            onModelClick.postMessage(JSON.stringify(intersection));
                          }
                        });
                      ''');
              },
            )

How to do it can you help me with that
Thanks
